# Ubuntu 16.04.03 After Installing on new SSD WiFi doesn't work

Tags: networking, wireless, uefi, ssd

After getting a new SSD I installed Ubuntu 16 on it. The only difference is now that I don't have Windows 10 on it and instead of UEFI, I have put it in Legacy Mode. Now there seems some kind of problem with my WiFi, because the connection is always dropping, while I am still connected to my WiFi. The problem is only on my Laptop! I have an Acer Aspire E15. Here are some outputs:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)

 sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp2s0
       Version: 15
       Seriennummer: 2c:60:0c:c7:93:bc
       Größe: 10Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:48 ioport:4000(Größe=256) memory:c4404000-c4404fff memory:c4400000-c4403fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Qualcomm Atheros
       Hersteller: Qualcomm Atheros
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp3s0
       Version: 30
       Seriennummer: b8:86:87:21:98:f1
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:54 memory:c4200000-c43fffff


$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ComThitRau2_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 78:11:DC:1B:1A:65   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:54  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Sorry that it's on German, but the outputs should have the same layout.

Comment: Please edit to include results from `iwconfig`

Comment: I have added the iwconfig output

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/913760/300665  wifi power management is enabled and the signal strength is a bit low, chili555's answer should help

Comment: Please see the following answer, I believe this may be what you need: https://askubuntu.com/a/878099/167115. Also, if that doesn't work, please follow the instructions at the following answer and run the wireless info script which will hopefully provide the information needed to diagnose the issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115

Comment: Also, be sure to set your regdom to the proper country. If you are in the EU I believe the correct is EU. However, from what I understand, EU has the most restrictive regulatory restrictions in place so it probably won't do you much good as far as strength is concerned. However, it *will* open up a few more channels for you to use, that is, assuming the regdom is currently set to 00.  The ath* series wifi devices seem to be buggy sometimes so that may be something worth looking in to.